# Can I start a new game without wiping the old game's saves?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Title speaks for itself, I'm actually only a little over half done with my current game but I may want to get a new game started soon. I've heard it's possible from [here](http://gtaforums.com/topic/444169-help-how-to-start-a-new-game-without-delete-old/), so long as you don't overwrite all of the name game saves over the old game saves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can basically start a new game whenever you want through the main menu. However, note that if your original game is only saved in the autosave, then you risk losing it by starting a new game.

So, how to start a new game without wiping your old save games (per instructions from the OPs link):

1. Enter your old game and trigger a save (eg complete a mission)
2. Turn autosave off
3. Start your new game
4. After completing a mission in the new game, save it to either another profile or save slot
5. Turn autosave back on

You should now have 2 save game slots, one with your old game and one with your new game.

[Source](http://gtaforums.com/topic/444169-help-how-to-start-a-new-game-without-delete-old/) (final answer in thread)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the reason I asked here is because I don't fully understand the final answer in the thread I linked. Do you know what is meant by 'another profile'? I get about 10 save slots in the game, would I somehow get 20 with another save, or would I have the second game save in my original slots? And which game would GTA 4 load up?

Comment: @exomute I haven't tried it, but I believe you would just have a different game in one of your save slots